# Force visitor to register in wordpress

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I tried so many plugins in my word-press website and i didn't find the correct plugin what I'm looking for.

In my website i have category called TOOLS i want when the visitors clicks on tools it will

display the posts normally but, when the the user click Continue Reading or Read More he must

be a registered and an approved user so he can read posts in category tools i tried a plugin called register plus but never mind didn't work anyone can help

me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add plugin custom plugin or somehow add user check when reading full post.
So what you need is to first check if user is on full post and if not logged redirect user to log in screen.
WP has functions just for that:

```
<?php if(is_single() )     auth_redirect(); ?>
```

Check out documentation for [`auth_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect) and for [`is_single()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single).

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin, it seems that it will do the job: https://www.volcanicpixels.com/password-protect-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: well it is good, but it's not what i expected, i have to let people register and not make a password and give it to them